# Using grep and pipes in Unix to find specific words

Tags: bash, unix, filter, grep, pipe

Let's say I'm using **grep**, and I use use the -v option on a text file to find all the words that do not contain vowels. If I then wanted to see how many words there are in this file that do not contain vowels, what could I do?

I was thinking of using a pipe and using the **rc** command by itself. Would that work? Thanks.

Comment: Every line contain several words or are the words arranged one per line?

Comment: Would -c ^[^aeiou]*$ not work?

Comment: @higuaro, the words are arranged one per line.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I believe that you want `wc`, not `rc`, as in:

```
grep -civ '[aeiouy]' words.txt
```

For example, consider the file:

```
$ cat words.txt
the
words
mph
tsk
hmmm
```

Then, the following correctly counts the three "words" without vowels:

```
$ grep -civ '[aeiouy]' words
3
```

I included `y` in the vowel list.  You can decide whether `y` or not it should be removed.

Also, I assumed above that your file has one word per line.

The grep options used above are as follows:

- `-v` means exclude matching lines
- `-i` makes the matching case-insensitive
- `-c` tells grep to return a count, not the actual matches

#### Multiple words per line

```
$ echo the tsk hmmm | grep -io '\b[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxz]*\b' | wc -l
2
```

Because `\b` matches at word boundaries, the above regex matches only words that lack vowels.  `-o` tells grep to print only the matching portion of the line, not the entire.  Because `-c` counts the number of lines with matches, it is not useful here.  `wc -l` is used instead to count matches.

Comment: In case there isn't one word per line, wouldn't `wc -w` be better?

Comment: @cdarke Because it would be possible for some words on the line have vowels and others not, a different approach is needed.  See updated answer.

Comment: `grep -civ` by itself already produces a count of non-matching lines.

Comment: @tripleee Excellent suggestion.  I checked and `-c` is [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html).  I updated the answer to use `-c`.  Curiously, `-c` mounts matching _lines_ of input, not the number of matches, so it is not useful here on the multiple-words-per-line case.

Answer (score 1):

The following script will count the number of words that don't contain vowels (if there are several words per line):

```
#!/bin/bash

# File can be a script parameter
FILE="$1"

let count=0
while read line; do
    for word in $line; do
        grep -qv "[aeiou]" <<< "$word"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
           let count++
        fi
    done
done < FILE
echo "words without vowels: $count"
```

If there is only one word per line, then the following will be enough:

```
grep -cv "[aeiou]" < file
```

Answer (score 0):

If multiple words can be on the same line, and you want to count them too, you can use `grep -o` with `wc -l` to count all the matches correctly, like so:

```
$ echo "word work no-match wonder" | grep -o "wo[a-z]*" | wc -l
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, alternatively, do this all within an Awk:

```
awk '!/[aeiou]/ {n++} END {print n}' file
```

For lines with multiple fields:

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i !~ /[aeiou]/) n++} END {print n}' file
```